# Azure sticky-session/sourceIP load balancing and instance probing

Tags: azure, load-balancing

We have a cluster of instances running as workerroles on Azure. They contain services that rely on state. Users connect via Socket.IO.

We need stickySessions, so that a client can stay with a single instance and the service that is running on it. If the user is re-routed to another instance, the client breaks.

**My questions:**

The LB distribution mode sourceIP will allow sticky sessions. But only as long the balanced instance set does not change (instance added/removed). When an instance is probed unhealthy, does the set change? And what does that mean for current users? Will they be re-routed?

What is a "new user" anyway? SourceIP uses a 2-tuple hash. Can i rely on clients sitting on the same system not being marked "new" when probes flag an instance unhealthy? Will they still be routed to that instance?

And lastly. Is there any sure and easy way to achieve sticky sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short story:

Any flow already established will persist unless of course the destination itself dies; this is about new flows only. The ability to pin all flows from a *specific source to a specific VM* irrespective of the health status of the backend pool is not supported in Azure Load Balancer and not what sourceIP distribution mode is.  If that is what you need, you can either use another tool in the arsenal or you can solve this by having each node reach out to wherever state is actually kept.

Read long story below for details.

#### Long story:

When you create an Azure Load Balancer function, the SDN stack uses the protocol header values to compute a hash.   The distribution mode choice governs which protocol header values are used to compute the hash:

- 5-tuple: source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port,
  protocol
- 2-tuple: source IP, destination IP

2-tuple is what is referred to as distribution mode sourceIP.  Since the destination IP is always that of the VIP when this is evaluated, only the source IP controls the hash. And because port numbers aren't considered, any session from a given source IP address will result in the same hash.

The hash determines where a new session lands.  The session will persist on that destination until the flow terminates.

If the pool changes because a node becomes healthy or sick, the hash will change and impact new flows only.

Any session already in progress stays wherever it is.  You just cannot guarantee a given source will always end up the same destination over time with a changing pool.

Here's an example:

Let's assume you have a scenario where you have VM's A, B, C in a pool behind an LB configuration.  You turn on sourceIP.

First session from client X comes in, lands on B.  As long as the pool stays the same (all nodes remain healthy and sick nodes aren't healed), any additional sessions from X will also land on B.

When the pool changes because a node changes health status from healthy to sick or vice versa, a new session from client X may land on a node other than B. Any sessions already on B remain on B.

Unless of course B itself is dead, in which case those established sessions will time out.